# How to control a log in

Tags: c#, security, authentication

So I created a custom generated file that lets me take the username and password.
It is the following:

```
public User GetUserByUserNamePassword(string userName, string Password)
{
   return (_DatabaseContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Username == userName && user.Password ==Password));
}
```

In my login page I have a `webUserControl` that contains two `textboxes`, one for the *password* and the other one for the *username*. 
I created an `object data source` for the webusercontrol to take in parameters Username and password .

What's the `c#` code that can let me check if the username and password are valid (I have a table called `User` btw that has three columns, *UserID(pk)*, *Username* and *Password*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is a three step process

1. You have to check whether the username and password submitted is not null
2. You have to use a foreach loop for the whole database and match the user id with the user id submitted by the user, same goes with the password
3. You have to notify the user about success or failure.

Tip:  donot go near the database if the username or password is null, otherwise you are exposing your database to hackers.

Comment: Can you please show me some code? just to guide me. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you consider as a valid username/password. You can use regex to check if it follows the right pattern before you return the User from the database. This is a good tutorial for Learning regex: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial